# Composite functional space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $K$. Let $V^{**}$ be the dual space of $V^{*}$. Show that each elelment $v\in V$ gives rise to an element $\lambda_v$ in $V^{**}$ and that the map $v\to\lambda_v$ gives an isomorphism of $V$ with $V^{**}$. Book ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang***

I tried to answer it on other thread. I am self-studying and I do not have any kind of solutions.

**For those who do not understand my terminology and the way I thought, here it is the proof in which I based my own for this exercise.**

> **Theorem**: Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, with a non-degenerate scalar product. Given a functional $L:V\to K$ there exists a unique element $v\in V$ such that: $L(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$
>
> for all $w\in V$.
>
> **Proof**. Consider the set of all functionals on $V$ which are of type $L_v$, for some $v\in V$. This set is a subspace of $V*$, because of the zero functional is of this type, and we have the formulas
>
> $L_{v_1}+L_{v_2}=L_{v_1+v_2}\:\:\:\:\:\text{and}\:\:\:\:\:L_{cv}=cL_{v}$
>
> Furthemore, if $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $L_{v_1},...L_{v_n}$ are linearly independent. Proof: If $x_1,...,x_n\in K$ are such that:
>
> $x_1L_{v_1}+...+x_nL_{v_n}=0\\L_{x_1v_1}+...+L_{x_n v_n}=0$
>
> and hence
>
> $L_{x_1v_1+...+x_n v_n}=0$
>
> However, if $v\in V$, and $L_v=0$, then $v=0$ by the definition of non-degeneracy. Hence:
>
> $x_1v_1+...+x_n v_n=0$,
>
> and therefore $x_1=...=x_n=0$, thereby proving our assertion. We conclude that the space of functionals of type $L_v\:(v\in V)$ is a subspace of $V*$, of the same dimension as $V*$, whence equal to $V*$. This proves the theorem.$\blacksquare$ Book: *"Linear Algebra" by Serge Lang*

Could someone write a complete proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First consider the space $V^*$.

Comment: Does Lang define $\lambda_v$? If so, include this in the question

Comment: The other thread being referred to is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2351531/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Lang does not define $\lambda_v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\phi \in V^{*}$, Define $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$.  Because we know that $\dim V = \dim V^* = \dim V^{**}$, it suffices to show that the map $\lambda_{\_}:v \mapsto \lambda_v$ is injective, i.e. that it has a trivial kernel.

Suppose, then, that $v \in \ker \lambda_{\_}$.  That is, $\lambda_v = 0$.  That is: for all $\phi \in V^*$, we have $\phi(v) = 0$.  However, whenever $v$ is non-zero, there exists a $\phi:V \to K$ such that $\phi(v) \neq 0$.  We may conclude, then, that $v \in \ker \lambda_{\_} \implies v = 0$.  So, $\lambda_{\_}$ has a trivial kernel.

So, $\lambda_{\_}$ is an isomorphism, as desired.

Comment: How do you know $\dim V = \dim V^* = \dim V^{**}$? What do you think of my proof in the other thread? Is it right or wrong?

Comment: How do you know $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$? This is something that has been troubling me since the other thread.

Comment: @PedroGomes I think your proof in the other thread assumes that $V$ has an inner product, which is a problem.  I am **defining** $\lambda$ in this way, so that's how I know it.  I'm not using your $L_v$ at all, since your $L_v$ does not make sense as you've decided to present it.

Comment: It was the book that defined the $L_v=\langle v,w\rangle$.

Comment: Anyway you forgot to answer why is $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$? And how do you know $\dim V = \dim V^* = \dim V^{**}$?

Comment: @Pedro I didn't forget. As I said, this is my definition of $\lambda$.

Comment: If we know that $\dim V= \dim V^*$ for any $V$, then we also know that $\dim V^*= \dim V^{**}$ for any $V$.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and now I am beginning to understand the points made. I would like to know: How do you know or assume $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$. Are you treating $\lambda$ as a constant and using the linearity of the linear functional?

Comment: @PedroGomes I am defining the object $\lambda$ by saying that for every $v$, $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$.  Note that $v \mapsto \lambda_v$ is linear, since for all scalars $\alpha,\beta \in K$, vectors $v,w \in V$, and functionals $\phi \in V^{*}$, we have
$$
\lambda_{\alpha v + \beta w}(\phi) = \phi(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha \phi(v) + \beta \phi(w) = \alpha \lambda_v + \beta \lambda_w
$$

Comment: What has been troubling me on this exercise is that I do not seem to understand the following two points 1) $\lambda_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$ 2) What is $V^{**}$? Is the space of the square functionals? Or are the elements the same in $V^{**}$ and $V^{*}$? I know point 1) and 2) are interconnected, however I do not see how point one can be true. Thanks for your effort, it has been fantastic!

Comment: The objects of $V^*$ are linear maps on $V$ whose output is an element of $K$.  For instance, the map $\phi_w:v \mapsto \langle v,w \rangle$ is an element of $V^*$ since its input $v$ is an element of $V$ and its output $\phi_w(v) = \langle v,w \rangle$ is an element of $K$.  The objects of $V^{**}$ are linear maps on $V^*$ whose output is an element of $K$.  For instance, the map $\lambda_v : \phi \mapsto \phi(v)$ is an element of $V^{**}$ since its input $\phi$ is an element of $V^*$ and its output $\phi(v)$ is an element of $K$.